# Eclipse reports unrooted test results for parameterized tests when run JUnit 5 with JUnit 4 runner

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-03.
I created a test class with parameterized tests using JUnit 5.
The code is here:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = dataDir + "TestPO/ddt.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
void invalidLogin(String username, String password, String errorMessage, TestInfo info)
{
    printDisplayTestName(info);
    
    LoginPage loginPage = LoginPage.open(driver);
    loginPage.submitLogin(username, password);
    assertTrue(loginPage.getConfirmation().contains(errorMessage));
}
```

When I run this test using JUnit 5 runner, it produces the correct results.
However when I run the same test class as a part of the test suite using JUnit 4 runner,

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
  @SelectClasses({
      TestPO.class,
      LoggingTest.class
  })
 
class Smoke
{}
```

where the *invalidLogin()* test is a part of the *TestPO* class, it works but results are presented as the *Unrooted Tests*.
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) is a workaround when you have to use (old) tools that do not support the JUnit5 platform. Do not use it with a recent IDE. Some things just cannot work because JUnit4 is missing out on fundamentals.

Comment: @johanneslink I must use @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) in Eclipse to run the test suites. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: @Vladimir No, you do not need to use `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` in Eclipse. By the way, your Eclipse is outdated.

Comment: Hand-crafted test  suites are not a supported concept in JUnit 5. Depending on what you want to achieve with them there are alternatives.

Comment: @johanneslink. JUnit 5 supports test suites. See the User's Guide. 4.4.4. Test Suite
If you have multiple test classes you can create a test suite as can be seen in the following example.

import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("JUnit Platform Suite Demo")
@SelectPackages("example")
public class JUnitPlatformSuiteDemo {
} What alternatives are you talking about?

Comment: @Vladimir RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) Is a workaround. I’m one of the original developers of JUnit 5, I know what it supports and what it does not.

Comment: @johanneslink, Now I'm really confused. So what I read in the User's Guide in JUnit 5 on test suites is wrong. The annotations SelectPackages and SelectClasses do not create the test suites? Please enlighten.

Comment: @Vladimir No it’s not wrong. But it clearly states: „Since the JUnit Platform has features that JUnit 4 does not have, the runner is only able to support a subset of the JUnit Platform functionality“

Comment: To sum up what @johanneslink says: With `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` you force your JUnit 5 tests to run via the JUnit 4 API (`[Runner: JUnit 4]`), although your Eclipse (even though you missed to upgrade it) supports both, JUnit 4 and JUnit 5. Piping the results for no reasons through the JUnit 4 API causes this minor glitch (and the why is explained in the documentation).